# "Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. ping to 127.0.0.1 failed!". can anyone say me how can i overcome this

Tags: python

I tried executing the code below, but I am getting an access denied error. How can I fix it?

```
 import subprocess

 for ping in range(1,10):    
     address = "127.0.0." + str(ping)
     res = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '3', address])
     if res == 0:
         print ("ping to", address, "OK")
     elif res == 2:
         print ("no response from", address)
     else:
         print ("ping to", address, "failed!")
```

Output:

```
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.2 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.3 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.4 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.5 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.6 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.7 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.8 failed!
 Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges. 
 ping to 127.0.0.9 failed!
```

Comment: what is the operating system you are running it on. Is this code part of framework view etc. or standalone script.

Comment: I am trying to run it using flask framework. ( windows os)

Comment: Was this code meant for unix? Under unix `ping -c 3 <address>` means _ping address 3 times_ and under [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx) it means _ping address on compartment (routing compartment) 3_ which needs Administrative/System rights.

Answer (score 1):

```
Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.
```

tells you that the process you are trying to run requires elevated permissions.

The easiest solution is to run the whole script with elevated permissions.

```
sudo ./script.py
```